# Keyboard Detection

Tags: ios, keyboard

I would like to run a method in my app when the keyboard shows up. 
Is there a predefined method or I have to create it?
And how to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a notification when the keyboard is going to show up:

```
UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
```

You can register the notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

More [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).